# What is the difference between element-range-index and field-range-index in marklogic?

Tags: indexing, marklogic

I am getting confused between `element-range-index` and `field-range-index` in MarkLogic.

Please explain the difference with the help of an **example**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of these are scalar indexes: sorted value-based indexes of a particular type. The only difference is in what parts of the documents are being selected to be included in the index.

An element range index selects those values from a particular named XML element wherever it occurs in a document. A field range index selects those values from the items selected by the field. Field selection can be more complex, consisting of multiple XPaths, or with sets of included and excluded elements. Fields can therefore be more targeted in what they are selecting.

For example, if you have a document

```
<document>
   <title>Example</title>
   <chapter>
       <title>Chapter 1</title>
   </chapter>
</document>
```

You could set up a string element range index on the element "`title`" and it would include the values "Example" and "Chapter 1". A field range index could be set of a field that selects the path "`/chapter/title`" and it would only include the value "Chapter 1".

Comment: Thanks!! Nicely explained